# Manage Springboot beans loading

Tags: dependencies, spring-boot, listener

I am using Springboot for my application modules. So the entire application consists of bunch of independent Springboot modules that can be started up simultaneously as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({A.class, B.class, C.class})
public class Starter{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      SpringApplication.run(Starter.class);
   }
}
```

Each of the A.java, B.java and C.java are Spring configuration files and consist of bean definations for the respective modules. Starter should basically run them all together, which works as expected.

However, the problem is that the classes A, B and C have internal dependencies. For example, B.java should start up only after all the beans from A.java have fully been loaded (not just initialized). Similarly, C.java should start up only after all the beans from B.java have fully been processed and loaded.

To capture the above scenarios I am adding ApplicationPreparedEvent listeners to capture when a particular class has been fully loaded for each of the modules, but this event is never being thrown. I have attempted using ApplicationReadyEvent, ContextRefreshed/ContextStarted events as well, but am not able to achieve the load order as above. I am following the Springboot documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners

Any ideas to resolve this would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What form do the internal dependencies take? it's not clear from your question why standard dependency injection isn't sufficient. Can you provide a concrete example of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You must add one more annotation for @ComponentScan